# How do I allocate same amount of resource for all my tasks deployed on a Celery cluster?

Tags: docker, resources, celery, virtual-machine, scheduler

To compare and contrast the performances of three different algorithms in a scientific experiment, I am planning to use Celery scheduler. These algorithms are implemented by three different tools. They may or may not have parallelism implemented which I don't want to make any prior assumption about. The dataset contains 10K data points. All three tools are supposed to run on all the data points; which translates to 30K tasks scheduled by the scheduler. All I want is to allocate the same amount of resources to all the tools, across all the executions.

Assume, my physical  Ubuntu 18.04 server is equipped with 24 cores and 96 GB of RAM. Tasks are scheduled by 4 Celery workers, each handling a single task. I want to put an upper limit of 4 CPU cores and 16 GB of memory per task. Moreover, no two tasks should race for the same cores, i.e., 4 tasks should be using 16 cores in total, each scheduled on its own set of cores.

Is there any means to accomplish this setup, either through Celery, or cgroup, or by any other mechanism? I want to refrain from using docker, kubernetes, or any VM based approach, unless it is absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with CPU cores should be fairly easy by specifying concurrency to 6. But limiting memory usage is hard part of the requirement and I believe you can accomplish that by making worker processes be owned by particular cgroup that you specified memory limit on.

An alternative would be to run Celery workers in containers with specified limits.

I prefer not to do this as there may be tasks (or task with particular arguments) that allocate tiny amount of RAM so it would be wasteful if you can't use 4G of RAM while such task runs.

Pity Celery autoscaling is deprecated (it is one of the coolest features of Celery, IMHO). It should not be a difficult task to implement Celery autoscaler that scales up/down depending on memory utilization.

Comment: I think the "concurrency" controls the number of processes spawned by a worker. Each process corresponds to an analysis task here. I think Celery, by default, doesn't limit how many threads each of the tasks task can issue.

Comment: I did not understand that you want to limit the number of threads spawned by your tasks. You are right, Celery does not control that either.